# Referencing a sub item of a container in controller

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to reference a sub item of a container by itemId in Sencha Touch 2 controller? For example, a container with xtype 'mypanel', it contains a button with itemId 'mybutton'. In controller, I would like to assign an even handler to the button. How do I do that?

My app is quite large and often has duplications of one component, so I don't use id anywhere in my app, instead I use itemId.

```
Ext.define('myapp.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {
            myButton: {
                tap: 'showView'
            }
        },
        refs: {
            myPanel: 'mypanel',
            myButton: '?'
        }
    },

    showView: function(){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
refs: {
    mybutton: 'mypanel #mybutton'
}
```

More information about ComponentQuery available here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Answer (score 0):

When using **itemId** instead of **id**, you also need to mention the parent that contains the element with an itemId in the controller's ref like this:

```
refs: {
    mybutton: 'xtype_of_panel #itemId_button'
    //where 'itemId_button' is the itemId and 'xtype_of_panel' is the parent that contains the element with the itemId of 'itemId_button'
}
```